# Problem with deleting an element from an array in React

Tags: reactjs, arrays, typescript

I have a `handleAd` function that adds new components to an array, and I also have a `handleDelete` function that is supposed to remove the selected element from the array.

am generating unique keys for each element, but because of this the elements are not being deleted. Initially, the key was the index of the array element, and in this case the elements were of course deleted, but not entirely correctly; when 1 element was deleted, the names of all other elements were deleted.

```
import React, { useState, ReactElement } from "react";
import Category from "./components/Category";
import "./css/style.css";

function App() {
  const [cardArray, setCardArray] = useState<ReactElement[]>([]);

  const handleAdd = () => {
    let key = Date.now() + Math.random();
    setCardArray((prevArray: ReactElement[]) => [
      ...prevArray,
      <Category key={key} onDelete={() => handleDelete(key)} />,
    ]);
  };

  const handleDelete = (index: number) => {
    setCardArray((prevArray: ReactElement[]) =>
      prevArray.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="categories">
        <div className="categories-block">
          <p>Categories</p>
        </div>
        <p className="plus" onClick={handleAdd}>
          +
        </p>
        <p className="plus">-</p>
      </div>
      <div className="subcategories">
        {cardArray.map((category, index) => (
          <div key={index}>{category}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What could be the reason for this behavior, and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is anti-pattern of React. Please consider refactor your code. Try not to store ReactElement in state. React state is supposed to only store data rather than UI element.

E.g. you can store keys as array in cardArray, and then render from the array like: `cardArray.map((key) => (<Category key={key} onDelete={() => handleDelete(key)}>))`.

Another issue is that the handleDelete is not dealing with keys but index, which is not matching how it's used in onDelete.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be that using a combination of Date.now() and Math.random() for generating keys may result in non-unique and unstable keys. To fix this, it's better to generate unique and stable keys for your elements by maintaining a separate key identifier for each element and using it consistently.

The expression **Date.now() + Math.random()** is not **guaranteed** to be unique because **Date.now()** returns the **current timestamp in milliseconds**, and **Math.random() generates a random floating-point number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive)**. If you generate keys in rapid succession, you might end up with the **same** **key** **value**.

```
// ... other code

const handleAdd = () => {
  const uniqueKey = `category-${Date.now()}`;
  setCardArray((prevArray) => [
    ...prevArray,
    { key: uniqueKey, component: <Category key={uniqueKey} onDelete={() => handleDelete(uniqueKey)} /> },
  ]);
};

const handleDelete = (keyToDelete) => {
  setCardArray((prevArray) =>
    prevArray.filter((item) => item.key !== keyToDelete)
  );
};

// ... other code
```